# How do i take a Value from a Cell and use it to complete a Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm about as green as you can be with VBA.  In a nut shell i have a report i run every month that shows me open files for my job.  I have been doing this all on my own and I am trying to automate some of my sorting and cleaning I do to the list.  We have 3 Sheets.

Worksheet 1: RAW Info (lists all of the open files I have in our system.  We run this each month to make sure we don't lose anyone that has contacted us.

Worksheet 2: this is literally the worksheet that has most of the my conditional formatting, dropdown lists, ect.

Worksheet 3: "Final Sheet" that has all the cleaned up data.  This workbook is exactly that a work book.  I plan on doing the following once I get this issue cleaned up:

Copy to another workbook which has all of our other monthly reports in it.  I am planning on having a cutton that will open the "Master" workbook, Add a new Tab, ask me to name that tab, and then copy the data I have just cleaned up.  Adding the conditional formatting that we have in place already (so the conditional formatting will move to that workbook eventually).

So, back to where I am having issues; I want to take the input box I created, after the user data is entered, and turn that data into part of a macro, but I don't know how to do it.

For instance, when the user input box pops up, I can type in ("A1:E20"), and that will appear under a heading in Sheet 2 (Worksheet).  But I then want that data for ("A1:E30") to be copied to Sheet 3 (Finished) in the correct location (in this case starting at ("E11").

What I am trying to figure out is if I type ("A1:E30") into the input box, and it places it on sheet 2, in Cell A12, what is the next part to get the parameters  ("A1:E30") from Cell A12 into

The last code I had just copied Cell A12 from Worksheet to Worksheet Finished E11 as the same thing ("A1:E30") instead of going to Sheet 1 (RAW Data) and copying cells A1:E30 and starting it in Finished Sheet at cell E11.

I hope that this makes sense I am just stumbling and I feel like a fool.

Here is the code I have its horrible and clumsy at its finest.

```
Sub TEST_Module()

Dim rng As Range

Dim myResponse As String

myResponse = InputBox("Enter Range Here", " Final Copy Range")
Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("A12").Value = myResponse
MsgBox ("Copying" & myResponse)
```

Comment: `MyResponse` is a string that your code places in `A12`. What is the problem? I can't figure out what it is you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am tryin gto then take the value in A12 Worksheet, and pass that onto a macro that is controlled on the Finished Sheet to copy the actual cells that were listed in A12 to begin with.

Comment: Let's say you do enter "A1:E30" - what sheet contains that range, and what exactly is to happen to the cells in that range?  `Set rng = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range(myResponse)` would create a `Range` object pointed to the specified range, but it's unclear what you want to do with that.

Comment: Ok, let me try and rephrase this as I am new and am frustrated.

Comment: Ok, let me retry this.  I have 3 Sheets in this Workbook.  Sheet 1 is where I do all the cleanup of data that I want to do.  Sheet 2 is just worksheet and is odds and ends that i am tinkering with, except, there is 5 cells that I am wanting to use with an Input Box to copy the cleaned up data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 3.  I will use this same form every month to do this same report.  Trying to not have to worry about changing VBA ranges every month

Comment: The code I provided dumps the Input Box data into Sheet 2 Cell A12.  I want to then be able to click a button and have a macro go to Sheet 2 Cell A12 grab the cell range that is listed and then go to Sheet 1 and grab that specific cell range and dump that cell range in Sheet 3 at the specific point I designate ie Cell E11.  Once this is done I can move on with what I want, but it's creating the code to tell VBA to go to Cell A12 grab that cell rage that is listed there, copy the data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 3 in the designated location.

Comment: `Sheet1.Range(Sheet2.Range("A12").Value).Copy` then `Sheet3.Range("E11").PasteSpecial` As Tim said you can just use your `myResponse` in the range field which means it can all be done at once instead of putting the range into A12 then pressing another button to copy the data. In the `.Range()` element you can put whatever you want so long as it references a valid range. Be it a cell value or a variable string etc.

Comment: Simon, I tried the code you put below and I ended up with an error.  The error was Run-Time error "9"  Subscript out of range.

Comment: Simon, the error popped on this line Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: Tim, I tried your solution up above and I got an error message "424" Object Required

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Simon's comment:

```vb
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, addr

Set wb = ThisWorkbook                'the workbook where this code is running
Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")    'copying from here
Set ws3 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet 3")   '...to here

addr = wb.Worksheets("worksheet").Range("A12").Value
ws1.Range(addr).Copy ws3.Range("E11")
```

Comment: Ok, I put this together and figured out 1 of my errors and that was I neglected to change Sheet 1 and Sheet 3 to the correct names, but when I did find this error, I still am getting an error of Run-Time Error "1004" Method 'Range' of Object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: Here is the total code:

Comment: When adding code you should edit your question and add it there - too difficult to read in a comment.

Comment: I've broken out that last line into two lines - which is the one which produces the error?

Comment: it is the final line of of the code, it is still giving me a 1004 Error Method Range of object '_Worksheet' failed.  Thank you for all your help on this.

Comment: Likely whatever is stored in A12 is not a valid range address.

Comment: Tim, I am entering the range as ("A1:E7") which is what VBA requires me to enter

Comment: Tim, I figured it out.  I was using the () and I decided to be crazy and just did A1:E7 and it worked.  Thank you folks so much for your help on this.  I feel a whole lot better lol

Comment: Good to hear you got it working